# Is there a difference between library(package) And library("package") in R?

Tags: r

If one reads various sources with respect to R, you will see different ways of loading add-on packages. In other posts the difference between require() and library() has already been explained.

But is there a difference between library(splines) as given in the help for library and library("splines"), hence using quotation marks? R seems to load the packages similarly under both cases. Which one is the correct one? Or does it not matter? In various books packages are loaded with library("package")

Comment: no, except that library(package) is possibly a little bit slower, as it needs to realise to convert the package argument into a character

Comment: ...and by slower, @Alex is referring to a tiny amount of time that you would miss if you blinked.